# Getting the Parent Window URL for iframe using SSJS

Tags: xpages

We have a corporate website which has an iFrame within a page pointing to my XPage.

The problem I have is that the same XPage is also used in another iFrame (different page) and I need to clear some Scope variables on beforePageLoad event.

Using SSJS; how can I get the parent window url for my iFrame content?

Example:

Corporate page #1 = `http://mycompany.com/training-courses`

Corporate page #2 = `http://mywebsite.com/training-ilo`

Both pages have an iFrame pointing to `http://dominoserver/myapp.nsf/xHome.xps`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless your domino server domain is the same as the parent sites, you will not be able to access information from those pages.

Your best bet is to supply a url parameter to the src of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://dominoserver/myapp.nsf/xHome.xsp?site=xyz"></iframe>
```

Then, in your ssjs of your xpage you can grab the url information using the XSPUrl class:

```
var url : XSPUrl;
url = context.getUrl();
var site = url.getParameterName("site");
```

Comment: "param" also returns a Map for access via SSJS, so param.get("site") should also work. Technically it's provided as an implicit object, like database, session, etc.